# append values to spinner dynamically

Tags: python, kivy, spinner

I'm trying to write some basic GUI using `Kivy`.

My program loads some data from a CSV file that contains an unknown number of rows.

The first column is called sValue which basically tells me the "id" of the spinner and the second column has a Name value.

My goal is to iterate all of the rows inside this CSV and to create dynamically x spinners based on the different numbers of "id" that the CSV has and in each spinner to show the values that it might have.

For example, if the CSV looks as follows:

```
sValue    Name
1           a
1           b
2           a
3           a
3           b
3           c
```

I want the code to create 3 spinners where in spinner 1 it will have the values a,b. spinner 2 will have the value a and spinner 3 will have a,b,c.

I wrote the following code however it only shows me the last value that was added (I guess because it always makes a new spinner instead of appending):

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App

import pandas as pd

def loadData():
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    SValues = range(min(data['sValue']),max(data['sValue']))
    return data, SValues

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Data, SValues = loadData()
        layout = self.initializeScreen(Data,SValues)
        return layout

    def initializeScreen(self, Data, SValues):
        self.spinnerObject = {}
        self.imageObject = {}
        complete_layout = FloatLayout()

        s_layout = FloatLayout()
        for ind, row in Data.iterrows():
            self.labelObject = Label(text='S %d' % row['sValue'], bold=True)
            self.labelObject.size_hint  = (1/len(SValues), 0.05)
            self.labelObject.pos_hint={'x': (row['sValue']-1)/len(SValues), 'y':0.8}
            s_layout.add_widget(self.labelObject)

            self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']] = Spinner(text='sValue %d' % row['sValue'], values=row['Name'])
            self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']].size_hint  = (1/len(SValues), 0.1)
            self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']].pos_hint={'x': (row['sValue']-1)/len(SValues), 'y':0.7}
            s_layout.add_widget(self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']])
    
            
        complete_layout.add_widget(s_layout)

        
        return complete_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

What I get looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your loop to add the values to existing `Spinner` instances:

```
    for ind, row in Data.iterrows():
        try:
            spinner = self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']]
        except:
            spinner = Spinner(text='sValue %d' % row['sValue'], values=[])
            self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']] = spinner
            self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']].size_hint = (1 / len(SValues), 0.1)
            self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']].pos_hint = {'x': (row['sValue'] - 1) / len(SValues), 'y': 0.7}
            s_layout.add_widget(self.spinnerObject[row['sValue']])
        spinner.values.append(row['Name'])
```